# Upload pictures from Yii showing endWiget() error

Tags: php, yii

Hi I also had a problem when try to upload picture using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671626/yii-uploading-pictures) method.

My Action/model:

```
class Image extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $foto;
    ...

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            ...
            array('foto', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png'),
            ...
        );
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
class ImageController extends Controller
{
    public function actionCreate()
    {
            $model=new Image;

            // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
            // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

            if(isset($_POST['Image']))
            {
                    $model->attributes=$_POST['Image'];
                    $model->image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'foto');
                    if($model->save())
                            $model->foto->saveAs('productimages');
                            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
            }

            $this->render('create',array(
                    'model'=>$model,
            ));
    }
}
```

My view:

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget(
            'CActiveForm',
            array(
                'id' => 'upload-form',
                'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
                'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
            )
    ); ?>

    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'foto'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'foto'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'foto'); ?>

    ...

    <div class="row buttons">
            <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); ?>
    </div>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

But when I run, two problems appeared:

Problem #1:
endWiget() call [SOLVED by Ivan Misic]

> ImageController contains improperly nested widget tags in its view "/var/www/html/onlineshop-nimalogos/protected/views/image/_form.php". A CActiveForm widget does not have an endWidget() call.

Problem#2:
Since problem # 1 is solved, came with another problem, the image is not saving at my 'productimages' folder.

Please help me with the problem # 2. Many thanks..

Comment: Follow this tutorial http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/624/upload-image-and-content-using-ajax-and-store-it-in-different-table/

Comment: According to the message the error is in the file _form.php. That view does not get called from this part of the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have somewhere opened redundant *CActiveForm widget* and you should look into views and partials.

Yii is generting three view files with gii, and these are:

```
create.php      update.php
    |               |
    |               |
    +-------+-------+
            |
            |
          _form.php
```

create and update views are rendering the same partial _form, so you should look in all three to find redundant *beginWidget* call.

The view you supported in your question should be _form.php partial view.

Comment: <?php $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
I found this at create & update view Thank's for the description about renderpartial. Now I get it. So when we 2 or more views are rendering same partial _form we only need call 1 endWidget at the partial form. Right?

Comment: That is right, but I am not sure if it is general rule, because some widgets might support nesting. In the case of the widget CActiveForm this cannot be done because it is a mere wrapper of HTML form tag which cannot contain another form tag in itself. Think of the partial as the code in part of the view which can be reused in several views, or moved in separate file for readability. So you could open and close widget in create view but then you would need to duplicate the code in update, so the logical place to put it is in the _form partial which is called by both of them.

Comment: renderPartial means it does not apply a layout to the rendered result(no header and footer included).
why we use _form
because we have same form for both create and update action.